# Accessing vector of structures

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I have a problem with accessing vector of structures in another structure. There might be something I cannot se ...

Lets have structure like this:

```
struct Struct_1 {
  int Id;
  int Mode;
  string Name;
};
```

Another structure like this:

```
struct Record {
  int Id;
  int StructId;
  string Name;
  vector<Struct_1> structHolder;
};
```

Now I need to fill some structures Record

```
int recordCount = 10;
vector<Record> recordVector(recordCount);
for(int i = 0; i < recordVector.size(); ++i){
   recordVector[i].Id = ...
   recordVector[i].StructId = ...
   recordVector[i].Name = ...
   // till now it is ok 
   recordVector[i].structHolder[i].Id = ..
   recordVector[i].structHolder[i].Mode = ..
   // and here it fails when i access vector

}
```

When I am trying to fill the data of structHolder, it fails with "C++ vector subscript out of range" Does anybody know where is a problem?
Thank you a lot!

Comment: The number of records != the number of structHolders. You must iterate  structHolder vector with the separate loop.

Comment: The default constructor of `Record` will set up `structHolder` as an empty vector. Either write a constructor, `.resize()` the vector before you use it, or use `structHolder.push_back(...)`

Comment: What *exactly* is this: `i recordVector.size()` supposed to be as a conditional clause of a for-loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fill the vector before you can access it. You can do it with `resize`, for instance:

```
vector<Record> recordVector(10);
int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < recordVector.size(); ++i) {
        recordVector[i].structHolder.resize(5);
        for (int j = 0; j < recordVector[i].structHolder.size(); j++) {
            recordVector[i].structHolder[j].Id = j;
            recordVector[i].structHolder[j].Mode = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

In this example every `recordVector` gets five `Struct_1` in its `structHolder` and we fill them with a nested loop.

Comment: Thank you! Helped me a lot. I figured it out that one loop was missing but I forgot to resize <vector> before second loop.

Answer (score 5):

`recordVector[i].structHolder` is an empty `std::vector`.
So you cannot access any item of it.

One solution is to fill an instance of `Struct_1` an `push_back` to your vector

```
Struct_1 myStruct;
myStruct.Id = 1
recordVector[i].structHolder.push_back(myStruct);
```

Answer (score 2):

Indexing into a nested `std::vector` accesses only existing elements in that vector. It can't add a new one. You need to initialize the data member `structHolder`, too, e.g.

```
for(int i = 0; i recordVector.size(); ++i){
   // as before...
   recordVector[i].structHolder.resize(42);

   // Now you can access the 42 Struct_1 instances via indexing:

   rectorVector[i].structHolder[0].Id = 10;
   // ...
}
```